# VBA -How to delete 2 rows above the row with a specific value

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I am very new to VBA and ran into this problem.
I want to delete 2 rows above a cell with specific value.

1. search a specific value (10+5 and 20+5) in column G
2. delete 2 rows above it because these two contain the same values in other columns.

I have tried this code but this didn't work.

```
Sub DeleteSuccessfulRows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x
For x = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row To ActiveCell.Row Step -1
    If Cells(x, 1) = "10+5" Then 'If we find this text
        Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete      'Delete the entire row
        Cells(x - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete  'Delete the row above it
        Cells(x - 2, 1).EntireRow.Delete  'Delete the row 2 rows above it
        x = x - 2
    'Delete blank rows
    ElseIf Cells(x, 1) = vbNullString Then Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

I added the picture of what my data looks like.
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: The moment you delete a row, the index changes. Delete all the rows together. For example `Rows(x - 2 & ":" & x).Delete Shift:=xlUp` BTW what did you mean by **these two contain the same values in other columns.**

Comment: `Cells(x, 1)` is looking to column "A" (=1) and not to "G". Use `Cells(x, 7)` or `Cells(x, "G")`. And do not modify the counter-variable in a `For`-loop. If you need to do so, use a `Do While`-loop

Comment: `because these two contain the same values in other columns.` if you mean that the other two rows have the same value as `10+5` then you do do not even need a loop. you can use autofilter to delete all rows which have `10+5`...

Comment: This may cause an error when x = 2. Because it could try to delete a row above row 1. Perhaps explain what it does or doesn't do. Do you get an error?